# How to add gradient to font face (CSS)?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, gradient

I'm looking for a way to add gradient to big bold letters like this: [image: http://gyazo.com/b127f359e01e12db0fb0d03d31f66f48.png?1334229785]

Words can have either one or two lines and font height varies depending on viewport height.

This example works in Chrome but not FF: http://dabblet.com/gist/1695257

Is there any working pure-CSS solution you would recommend?

Comment: No, what you want is still in the "proposal" stage. It will be a while before browsers agree on this.

Comment: How is the the method used in that link not pure CSS?

Comment: @JoshDavenport It is pure CSS, but not _working_ CSS!

Comment: @MrLister: Absolutely. That comment was in reference to the original question though

Comment: There are several tricks to do text gradients, each with its own limitations: http://google.com/search?q=css+tricks+text+gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree what Nathaniel said above, but if you still want to try it, then you can do this:

[Sample Code @ Codepen](http://codepen.io/LeftOverCoder/pen/FiegE)

```
<style>
h1 {
font-size: 60px;
text-align: center;
margin: 40px;
color: #000;
}

h1.methodA {
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1965a9, #000);
background: linear-gradient(top, #1965a9, #000);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

h1.methodB {
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.3) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1));
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,.3) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1));
}
</style>

<h1 class="methodA">Awesome Gradient Text Method A</h1>

<h1 class="methodB">Awesome Gradient Text Method B</h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible **at all** to do this in pure css in *non-webkit* browsers. Your example is the correct way to do it in webkit, but I would do a webkit detection media query just to make sure Firefox never tries to use the gradient without the text clip (read [CSS prefixes are becoming a threat - but is Webkit really to blame?](http://c.nath.is/FmLH)) like [so](http://dabblet.com/gist/2367442). May I remind you, this is *non-spec* stuff, and you really shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score -2):

The point is that this feature is not very easily compatible with different browsers however I took the time to google it for you and found this:
http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/

hope it helps you out.

EDIT: the people in the comments made me aware of the fact that this will not work for text therefor I found this other article wich gives you the answer to that:
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect

Comment: OP wishes to gradient text, not backgrounds

Comment: I think that above method can be applied to any object not just backgrounds since text can be returned as an object with w and h properties

Comment: @dennis No, background gradients are images. You cannot apply an image to a text. Try it for yourself.