# How do I use a gradient as a font color in CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do I use a gradient as a font color in CSS, without using images? I want to support Firefox.

I have used this code but it's not supported in Firefox:

```
<div class="text1"> Gradient Text</div>

.text1
 {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0F3, #F00);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code/ css; we're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: Doesn't appear possible for Firefox - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122647/how-to-add-gradient-to-font-face-css

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox text gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155961/firefox-text-gradient)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can use multiple spans that are positioned on top of each other and assign a different height and color to each of them. Its really ugly coding wise, but it works. 
http://jsfiddle.net/7yBNv/

Text selection is behaving a bit funky, but not too bad. And copying copies several entries (depending on which layer is selected) So I'd say you are better of solving this with svg's.

(I got the answer from here ,check there for more details: http://www.bagnall.co.uk/gradient_text.asp)

html:

```
<h1 class="Gradient">Sample Gradient Text (h1)
   <span class="G1" aria-hidden="true">Sample Gradient Text (h1)</span>
   <span class="G2" aria-hidden="true">Sample Gradient Text (h1)</span>
   <span class="G3" aria-hidden="true">Sample Gradient Text (h1)</span>
   <span class="G4" aria-hidden="true">Sample Gradient Text (h1)</span>
   <span class="G5" aria-hidden="true">Sample Gradient Text (h1)</span>
</h1>
```

css:

```
.Gradient{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 28px;
}
.Gradient,
.Gradient .G1,
.Gradient .G2,
.Gradient .G3,
.Gradient .G4,
.Gradient .G5{
    height: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: #4a778b;
    font-family: century gothic,helvetica,arial;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.Gradient{
    position: relative;
}
.Gradient .G5{
    height: 10px;
    color: #81a4b4;
    z-index: 6;
}
.Gradient .G4{
    height: 13px;
    color: #789eae;
    z-index: 5;
}
.Gradient .G3{
    height: 16px;
    color: #6f96a6;
    z-index: 4;
}
.Gradient .G2{
    height: 19px;
    color: #618a9c;
    z-index: 3;
}
.Gradient .G1{
    height: 22px;
    color: #547f92;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: True, but I don't see another way to do it crossbrowser & css only.

Comment: I love downvoters, who vote down a not perfect but working solution, without providing a better answer.

Comment: I'm doing an html to image and this is what works for me, the background clip solution just ends up looking dumb. Thank you @cytofu

Answer (score 19):

**Firefox Support:**
Unfortunately, only WebKit browsers implemented text-fill-color.
There is no workaround for Mozilla yet.

**Awesome post to this by Lea Verou:**
http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/

**Demo for WebKit:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ondrek/trr67/

**Code of HTML and CSS:**

```
<h1>hello</h1>

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

**How to generate own gradient:**
You can also generate own gradient at
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

**Duplicate to a question on:**
[CSS3 Gradient not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291484/css3-gradient-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: That's for webkit browsers only, OP requested for Firefox.

Comment: Why offer it as an answer to a question specifically relating to Firefox then?

Comment: @TheBlueDog I think it's still a valuable contribution for other people searching for an answer.

Comment: Everyone check @Amir Ahmad's 2016 answer!

Comment: how to do it on IE 11?

Answer (score 6):

```
.text1
 {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0F3, #F00);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0F3, #F00);
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
 }
```

you have to specify vendor prefix for firefox

Answer (score -5):

You can use this **generator** [textgradient.com](http://www.textgradient.com) to do CSS gradient texts.