# Rainbowcolored-string from left to right

Tags: javascript

I just recently startet with Javascript and had the following Idea:
I would like to have short text (maybe just a headline) on my website which single chars will have a rainbow-color that travells from left to right.

So I wrote this short script.

```
var Count = 6;

setInterval(function RainbowColorFunction()
{
            var Rainbow_Colors = ["#FFFF00","#FF7F00","#FF0000","#9400D3","#4B0082","#0000FF","#00FF00"];
            var Color_Element = document.getElementById("RainbowColorText");
            var Color_String = Color_Element.textContent;
            var Letter = "";
            var NewText = "";

            var RainbowCount = Count;

            var Stringlenght = Color_String.length;



                Color_String = reverse(Color_String);

            for (var i = Stringlenght, min = 0; i > min; i--) 
            {

                Letter = Color_String.charAt(i -1);
                if(Letter == " ")
                {
                    NewText += Letter;
                    continue;
                }                   

                NewText += Letter.fontcolor(Rainbow_Colors[RainbowCount]);

                RainbowCount--;
                if(RainbowCount < 0){RainbowCount = 6;}

            }
                Count--;
                if(Count < 0){Count = 6;}


                Color_Element.innerHTML=NewText;

}, 60);

function reverse(s) {
return (s === '') ? '' : reverse(s.substr(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

My Issue is now that the text changes colour from right to left. But I want it the other way around. Without the reverse Function my text is a big mess, but I am quite sure thats the point where I have to change things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: just increment instead of decrement Count:

```
Count++;
if(Count>6 ){Count = 0;}
```

Other observations:

- it's "length" not "lenght"
- try to use singlequotes in Javascript and doublequotes for html
  attributes. You will see that writing html in javascript and the
  reverse become simple.
- also the naming conventions for Javascript usually use lowercase
  Camel variables, uppercase is reserved for class names, public
  members maybe, etc. Whatever you use, be consistent after you choose.
- you can move a lot of the function outside the interval, like the
  part that gets the element.
- you don't need to name the function that you give setInterval as an
  attribute. Alternately you can name it then use
  setInterval(functionName,500) on a separate line.

If I would do it, I would try to encapsulate it better. Here is my 5 minute effort:

```
function RainbowColor(elem)
{
    this.Colors=["#FFFF00","#FF7F00","#FF0000","#9400D3","#4B0082","#0000FF","#00FF00"];
    this.Speed=16.66;
    this.Direction=1;
    this._offset=0;
    this._elem=elem;
    this._originalContent=elem.innerHTML;
}

RainbowColor.prototype={
    Colorize:function() {
        var self=this;

        function mod(v,l) {
            var result=v%l;
            return result<0?result+l:result;
        }

        function rainbowColorFunction() {
            var text=self._elem.textContent;
            var result='';
            var k=self._offset;
            for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
                var letter=text.charAt(i);
                if (!letter) continue;
                result+=letter.fontcolor(self.Colors[mod(k,self.Colors.length)]);
                k-=self.Direction;
            }
            self._elem.innerHTML=result;
            self._offset++;
        }
        this._interval=setInterval(rainbowColorFunction,1000/self.Speed);
    },
    Stop:function() {
        if (this._interval) clearInterval(this._interval);
    },
    Restore:function() {
        this._elem.innerHTML=this._originalContent;
    }
}

var colorizer=new RainbowColor(document.getElementById('RainbowColorText'));
colorizer.Colorize();
setTimeout(function() { colorizer.Direction=-1; },5000);
setTimeout(function() { colorizer.Colors=['lightgray','gray','black'] },10000);
setTimeout(function() { colorizer.Speed=10; },15000);
setTimeout(function() { colorizer.Stop(); },20000);
setTimeout(function() { colorizer.Restore(); },23000);
```

I also looked into using CSS to create a text gradient, but I couldn't find any cross-browser solution (More details : [How do I use a gradient as a font color in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882162/how-do-i-use-a-gradient-as-a-font-color-in-css))

Speaking of cross-browser, perhaps you should use jQuery to get and set HTML content in order for this to work everywhere correctly.