# How can I create a rainbow effect on my text?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have this text:
"Lorem ipsum";

I know how to make the entire text color change, but how can I make change gradually from left to right or from right to left?

Thank you!

Comment: you are looking at add a gradient to the text. Have a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a gradient as a font color in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882162/how-do-i-use-a-gradient-as-a-font-color-in-css)

Answer (score 2):

```
.Rainbow {
background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
color:transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t3wdgw30/

Answer (score 1):

try [background-clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

```css
body{text-align:center}

h1{
  font-size: 60pt;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 8ch 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #57365a 0ch, Yellow 1ch, Indigo 1ch, Indigo 2ch, Blue 2ch, #2f732e 3ch, Orange 3ch, Orange 4ch, Violet 4ch, Violet 5ch, Green 5ch, Green 6ch, #5b2979 6ch, Red 7ch);
}
```

```html
<h1>background-clip</h1>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can animate this rainbow? Like blue moving from left to right and something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using **linear-gradient** and **background-clip** property as,

check [updated fiddle with animation here](https://jsfiddle.net/jpe81nd6/3/)

change the **animation time** and **background size** accroding to your requirement.

**HTML**

```
<h1>Rainbow</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 72px;
    /* Here you can change angle of gardient also as 45deg here */
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,#FF0000,#FF7F00,#FFFF00,#00FF00,#0000FF,#4B0082,#8B00FF);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size:100%;
}
```

**CSS For animating gardient**

```
h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 72px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,#FF0000,#FF7F00,#FFFF00,#00FF00,#0000FF,#4B0082,#8B00FF);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 400% 400%;

    -webkit-animation: rainbowanim 10s ease infinite;
       -moz-animation: rainbowanim 10s ease infinite;
            animation: rainbowanim 10s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbowanim {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbowanim {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes rainbowanim { 
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can animate this rainbow? Like blue moving from left to right and something like that.

Comment: This is outstanding. Thank you.